# How to replace last curly brace in a PHP file

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to parse a php code using some regex and I'm stuck at how to use preg_replace() to replace the last } with the string I want. Here's a sample code:

```
$data = '<?php

 class Myclass {
      function index() {

      }
 } // <- I want to replace that curly brace

?>';

  $data = preg_replace('##is','// my new string here',$data);
```

Any idea how ?

Comment: please, give an example of your input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Find last curly brace and replace all characters after it with a string

Using the search pattern: `"(\})[^\}]*$"` should do it:

```
$pattern = "(\})[^\}]*$";
preg_replace($pattern, $replaceWith, $subject);
```

### Find last curly brace and replace only the brace itself with a string

Use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) such as this: `\}(?!.*\})`

More info: http://frightanic.wordpress.com/2007/06/08/regex-match-last-occurrence/

Comment: This code remove strings after last curly braces once replacement is made

Comment: No problem, we'll use a negative lookahead then: `\}(?!.*\})` http://frightanic.wordpress.com/2007/06/08/regex-match-last-occurrence/

Answer (score 2):

Find the position of the last `{` using `strpos` and then use `substr_replace`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try: `\}(?!.*\})`

Answer (score 0):

@Noufal Ibrahim suggests a better solution. I wrote a function that implements this solution.

```
function _injectCodeInClassDefinition($classString, $newCode, $comment="automatic patcher") {
    $replaceWith = "// BEGIN code injected by $comment\n$newCode\n// END code injected by $comment\n";
    $pos = strrpos($classString, '}');
    return substr_replace($classString, $replaceWith, $pos, 0);
}
```

Example usage (adding a new function to a class file)

```
$filePath = '/webroot/app/code/local/VendorX/ModuleY/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php';

$newClassCode = _injectCodeInClassDefinition(
    file_get_contents($filePath),
    "\tprotected function _isAllowed() { return true; } // ToDo: Fix this to actually check the ACL",
    "SUPEE-6285 compatability fix"
);

file_put_contents($filePath, $newClassCode);
```